# Join four tables in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to join four tables, with almost the same data together.

```
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| tableone.letters | tabletwo.letters | tablethree.leters | tablefour.letters |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 'a'              | 'a'              | 'a'               | 'a'               |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 'b'              | 'b'              | 'b'               | 'e'               |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 'c'              | 'c'              | 'c'               | 'g'               |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 'd'              | 'd'              | 'e'               |                   |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 'e'              | 'f'              |                   |                   |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 'f'              | 'g'              |                   |                   |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 'g'              | 'h'              |                   |                   |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 'h'              | 'i'              |                   |                   |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 'i'              |                  |                   |                   |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
| 'j'              |                  |                   |                   |  |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--+
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT tableone.letters, tabletwo.letters, tablethree.letters, tablefour.letters FROM querytesting.tableone
    FULL JOIN querytesting.tabletwo
    ON tableone.letters = tabletwo.letters
    FULL JOIN querytesting.tablethree
    ON tabletwo.letters = tablethree.letters
    FULL JOIN querytesting.tablefour
    ON tablethree.letters = tablefour.letters;
```

When I join them I get the following result:

```
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "a"  | "a"  | "a"  | "a"  |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "b"  | "b"  | "b"  | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "c"  | "c"  | "c"  | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "d"  | "d"  | null | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "e"  | null | null | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "f"  | "f"  | null | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "g"  | "g"  | null | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "h"  | "h"  | null | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "i"  | "i"  | null | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "j"  | null | null | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "k"  | null | null | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| "l"  | null | null | null |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| null | null | "e"  | "e"  |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
| null | null | null | "g"  |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
```

This is not the result I expected. I wanted the 'e' and 'g' in the third and fourth column to line up perfectly with the 'e' and 'g' in the first column.

Is there any way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: when i understand your problem, you have to join them all on the first tabel. FULL JOIN querytesting.tablethree
    ON tabletwo.letters = tablethree.letters must be  FULL JOIN querytesting.tablethree
    ON tableone.letters = tablethree.letters , also the last join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your explanation all you need to do is FULL JOIN all tables with `tableone`, though I'm not exactly sure if this is the actual intention specially if all data is only sample. Here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tableone.letters, tabletwo.letters, tablethree.letters, tablefour.letters 
  FROM tableone
      FULL JOIN tabletwo
           ON tableone.letters = tabletwo.letters
      FULL JOIN tablethree
           ON tableone.letters = tablethree.letters
      FULL JOIN tablefour
           ON tableone.letters = tablefour.letters;
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/acc44/4